# Error when using pca to reduce dimensionality

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, pca, dimensionality-reduction

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca =PCA(n_components =2)
X_PCA =PCA.fit(data_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

python is case sensitive - thus if your object is named pca, you cna't use PCA instead.
try:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca =PCA(n_components =2)
X_PCA =pca.fit(data_x)
```

Comment: Oh shoot, didn't notice that.